# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost.sklearn' only on cloud. It works locally

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, xgboost

i have a problem with module xgboost.sklearn.

I have a project developed with visual studio code (+ azure extensions). I write in python. I need to import xgboost.sklearn so i add this to requirements.txt:

```
azure-functions
azure-cosmos

pybind11
scipy==1.5.4

pyyaml==6.0
numpy==1.19.5
pandas==1.1.5
scikit-learn==0.24.2
xgboost==0.80
```

I run it locally (F5 - start debugging). Everything works just fine. So i deployed functions and call my endpoint. I got 500:
Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xgboost.sklearn' Stack:.......
(line with import xgboost.sklearn)

I try pip freeze > requirements.txt - not working
I have "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true in settings.json
My resources on Azure contains xgboost and sklearn (.python_packages/lib/site-packages): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg9Ur.png)

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, When I tried deploying with manually given requirements.txt I have received the similar issue. This is working fine after following the below steps.

*Step1:* Installed the scikit-learn and xgboost locally and then generated rerequirements.txt file using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

[image]

*Step2:* Now deployed the function to Function App

[image]

Then I have tested my function App which executed successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, new versions works for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hit and trail on multiple versions of scikit-learn to install and see what works.